# Weird "bounce" movement on tableView

Tags: iphone, tableview

I have a tableview with a large textArea that scrolls and whenever I drag the screen down an inch or so and release it it "bounces" back to the original position.  I want it to stay at the place where I dragged it.  Then if I drag it about 3 or more then it stays at that location.  If I flick it then it "springs" ahead a page of text.  Weird behavior and I am not sure how to make it normal.

I have tried disabling the bounce options and this didn't change the behavior. Any ideas what would cause this type of movement?

Comment: sounds like you have both the tableview and the textview doing scrolling. Try disabling scrolling on one of them.

Comment: Well this wasn't the problem, but it led me to the right area.  When I disabled the sculling on the srollbar it didn't change it.  But then I disabled paging on the tableview and this handled it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had my "paging" enabled and this is what caused the weird "bounce" motions.  Paging is self-explanatory and literally sets your scrolling to scroll a page at a time, instead of bit by bit like you may be used to.